# Stuck with Flask-Sqlalchemy Relationship system

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to create database, that consist user info(sqlite db)

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    login = db.Column(db.String(10), unique = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(20), unique = True)
    psw = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=True)
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<User {self.id}>"
```

This is what i already did.
I want to create fields upcoming_friends, incoming_friends, friends, i think that i need to create a new class that will extends user , but I did not find the documentation and don't understand how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `User`  table stores the information that you need about a particular user. If you want to find out what friends this `user` might have in your application, then you can create another table called `Friends`.

```py
class Friend(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    upcoming_friends = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True)
    incoming_friends = db.Column(db.String(64), unique = True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Friends: {self.id}>"
```

To create a relationship between these two database structures, we will do as follows:

```py
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    login = db.Column(db.String(10), unique = True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(20), unique = True)
    friends = db.relationship('Friend', backref='<give-a-reference>', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<User {self.id}>"
```

The `user_id` field was initialized as a foreign key to `user.id`, which means that it references an `id` value from the `user`'s table. In this reference the `user` part is the name of the database table for the model.

There is a bit of inconsistency when it comes to referring to the `user` table in `db.ForeignKey`. Here, you can see that the `user` table starts with a lower case, whereas when it comes to referencing `Friend` table in `db.relationship` we begin with an upper case.